# How to show an Important feature from a list?

Tags: interaction-design

I have a List :

-option x, for everyday use.

---

-option y ..

---

-option z..

---

-**option XXX, It's amazing** !

---

Option  XXX is a main feature, but is  not on the top of list as option X is most widely used.
What can be the best way to highlight this option?

Also, would it be better if I use option XXX outside the list and show it as a checkbox? I mean as the user will only notice it if he clicks on the list.What best can be done?

PS: It's a mobile application.

Comment: If it's the most important, why isn't it at the top? Alternatively, visual cues like mentioned in neophytes answer are good for drawing the eye (star or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listed at the top might not be enough, because it'll just appear to be apart of an ordinary list. Why not be more clear and direct:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUfKRJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Another example:

[Host gator](http://www.hostgator.com/web-hosting) (They directly say "we recommend") and it's not even a vertical list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As all the options belongs to the same category you should not bring one option out of the list as it can create all sorts of confusion for the user.

For me checkbox is also not an option as he won't get to know why this is the best option and usually it's human instinct to avoid extra click.

So I would go with a small sticker add a sticker "famous" for mostly used option and a "recommended " sticker for the best option that's it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response.What if the option is from a different category? Can I use it as a checkbox? Or a radio button to turn the feature on/off?

Comment: In that case I don't think that should be problem